# No me ejecuta el npm run test

Tags: reactjs

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Documentos\react\03-counter-app-vite\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/Users/kevin/OneDrive/Documentos/react/03-counter-app-vite/jest.config.js:1:1   
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:183:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
    at async requireOrImportModule (C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Documentos\react\03-counter-app-vite\node_modules\jest-util\build\requireOrImportModule.js:65:32)
    at async readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Documentos\react\03-counter-app-vite\node_modules\jest-config\build\readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:132:22)
    at async readConfig (C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Documentos\react\03-counter-app-vite\node_modules\jest-config\build\index.js:216:18)
    at async readConfigs (C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Documentos\react\03-counter-app-vite\node_modules\jest-config\build\index.js:404:26)
    at async runCLI (C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Documentos\react\03-counter-app-vite\node_modules\@jest\core\build\cli\index.js:182:59)
    at async Object.run (C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Documentos\react\03-counter-app-vite\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\index.js:155:37)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! counter-app@0.0.0 test: `jest --watchAll`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the counter-app@0.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-28T12_57_53_545Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Bro dale formato a tu pregunta no se entiende nada

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error te esta dando la respuesta.

```
...To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension. at file:///C:/Users/kevin/OneDrive/Documentos/react/03-counter-app-vite/jest.config.js:1:1
```

Básicamente, es cambiar la extensión de `.js` a `.cjs` en el archivo `jest.config`

Comment: muchas gracias!!!